# Verify E-Mail Delivery and Readership

Tags: email, smtp

When sending an email, is there a way to find out:

1. User has received the email (displayed in user's inbox).
2. User has read (and at what time) the email.

If it's not possible, what prevents it from finding out? What is the route an email message follows from sender to receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send an email, the email is transferred through a series of servers using [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol).  Once the email reaches it's destination it is stored into the recipients directory.  To retrieve and read the email, the recipient uses and email client like Outlook to that connects to the server via [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol)/[POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) which tells them how many new emails they have and delivers each message to the client.  In order to get this information, the user must provide their credentials.

So, in order to get this information you would need to know the imap/pop3 server(s) for the recipient's domain, as well as the recipient's login credentials (which would give you full access to the recipients email account). Basically, this is not possible.

[This article](http://whatismyipaddress.com/mail-server) gives a nice simple overview of how email gets sent over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and you do not need the credentials as mentioned in the selected answer.

Lets imagine you are using apache and php + mysql.

You send person x an email,
In the email you have an embedded image (your logo) which resides on your server.
the url of the logo in the email, points to a file on your server: 
example.com/logo.png?userRelatedId which is a php file.
with an htaccess (apache) you can state that logo.png gets executed with php and in fact forwards a real image and correct mimetype but before that identifies userRelatedId, and saves in your database with the time the file was accessed,

Meaning the email was read by person x and the time which the logo was accessed (email was looked at).